# Is there a term for the class of conic sections revolved around an axis (sphere, ellipsoid, paraboloid, hyperboloid)?

Tags: terminology, conic-sections, solid-of-revolution

I can't find a general term better than "3D conic sections" for these solids of revolution.  Does anyone know how to categorize these particular solids of revolution?

Comment: All of these surfaces are *quadric surfaces*, that is, surfaces in $\Bbb R^3$ defined a quadratic equation---but not all quadrics are surfaces of revolution (e.g., hyperbolic paraboloids and tri-axial ellipsoids are not).

Comment: Besides **quadrics**, some old texts may use the term **conicoids**.